# web2py: allow named users to add localizations / translations

Tags: permissions, localization, web2py

I would like to allocate some usernames/passwords in a web2py app and allow those users access to the languages updating pages (e.g. http://foo.com/admin/edit_language/myApp/languages/fr.py). Can I do this without giving them general admin access? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality that allows you to specify users with limited access to only parts of the admin app -- there is one login, and it is all-or-nothing access. However, the admin interface is itself just a web2py application, so you can edit the app and add your own access control logic.

Also, note that translations are simply stored in text files in an application's /languages folder, so you could provide some alternative interface allowing users to edit those files.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's not as easy as decorating e.g. the edit_language() function in the default admin controller with @auth.requires_membership(xxx) is it? I presume unless you have admin rights you won't even get this far?

Comment: Correct -- if you are not logged in via the admin login, you will get kicked to the admin login page from the /models/access.py model file (i.e., you'll never make it to any controller function). So, you'll need to add some custom code to /models/access.py.